# Python unittest AssertionError <names.Person object at 0x0293A6B0>> !=

Tags: python, unit-testing

I started unittest today and I ran into a problem, I feel like it is something obvious but maybe you guys will see it. 
This block is the file that holds the information

```
names.py

class Person:
  def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, middlename = ""):
    self.firstname = firstname
    self.lastname = lastname
    self.middlename = middlename
  def fullname(self):
      if self.middlename:
          return self.firstname + " " + self.middlename + " " + self.lastname

      else:
          return  self.firstname + " " + self.lastname
```

and this is the test app

```
import unittest
from names import Person




class TestName(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_fullname(self):

        rashka = Person("John","Smith","James")

        self.assertEqual(rashka.fullname, "John James Smith")

if __name__ == "__main__":
      unittest.main()
```

and I am getting this error when I run it

```
    AssertionError: <bound method Person.fullname 
    of <names.Person object at 0x0371A690>> != 'John James Smith'
```

Comment: You need to call the method: `rashka.fullname()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other answers have suggested, `fullname` is a method on your instance and so needs to be called like any other function:

```
>>> rashka.fullname
<bound method Person.fullname of <names.Person object at 0x0371A690>>

>>> rashka.fullname()
'John James Smith'
```

As an alternative, you might also consider using the `property` decorator to get attribute access:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, middlename = ""):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.middlename = middlename

    @property            # <-- new
    def fullname(self):
        if self.middlename:
            return self.firstname + " " + self.middlename + " " + self.lastname
        else:
            return  self.firstname + " " + self.lastname
```

Now, `rashka.fullname` will return the name (no parentheses needed), as you wrote in your test.

```
>>> rashka.fullname
'John James Smith'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `rashka.fullname()` else you're comparing a method to a str.